# How to get value from html select tag option value using onChange event using jQuery data table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on jQuery Data table to load few data from mysql database.

**Here is the html code :**

```
<table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**From php page I'm loading the data like bellow :**

```
// skipping more code...

$nestedData[] = "
<select class='form-control changeStatus' name='status'>
    <option value=''>--Select--</option>
    <option value='1|$client_id' $statusMsg1>Active</option>
    <option value='2|$client_id' $statusMsg2>Blocked</option>
</select>";
```

**Now the loaded data is look like this :**

[image]

Now I want to call the an `Ajax` request when html `selected` option value is change. It's calling `Ajax` request successfully by bellow code.

**jQuery code for jQuery Data Table and My Ajax Request :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url :"server_processing.php", // json datasource
            type: "post",  // method  , by default get
            error: function(){  // error handling
                $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

            }
        }
    } );

    $("#employee-grid").on('change', function() {
        var status = $('.changeStatus').val();
        alert(status);
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo SITE_URL . 'toplevel/update-data'; ?>",
            data : {
                'statusChange' : status
            }, 
            type : 'POST',
        });
    });

});
```

but When I select the option then every time it's passing **first option value**

For e.g. This `selected` option tag has these value :

```
<option value='1|11' $statusMsg1>Active</option>
<option value='2|11' $statusMsg2>Blocked</option>
```

It's always passing `1|11` value !! It's should be pass my selected option value. I don't understand why it's happening :(

Note : I think using jQuery data table custom jquery code should be use in different way.

Comment: Are there multiple rows being printed from PHP or just that single one?

Answer (score 1):

Well Guys,

I have solved it. I need to use something like that :

```
$('#employee-grid').on('change', '.changeStatus', function(){
    // testing.....
    var status = $('.changeStatus').val();
    alert(status);
});
```

The solution is to use event delegation by providing selector for target element as a second argument in on() call.